# Find particular solution of the linear nonhomogenous relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The math teacher has given us this example: Find the general solution of the linear nonhomogenous relation $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}+ F(n)$, where

$a)$ $F(n)=n^2(-2)^n$

$b)$ $F(n)=n2^n$

$c)$ $F(n)=n^24^n$

$d)$ $F(n)=(n^2-2)(-2)^n$

$e)$ $F(n)=n^42^n$

I know that, to find out the general solution must be assigned sum of the homogenous solution and the particular solution of the linear nonhomogenous relation $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}$.
My attemp is:
Associated homogenous recurence relation is: $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}.$
Charectestic equation: $r^2-8r+16=0$. Charectestic root is $r_0=4.$ So $a_n^{(h)}=\alpha4^n+\beta n4^n.$

But i didnt know how to find the particular solution. Help me to find the particular solution $a_n^{(p)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is of the form $D a_n = F(n) $, where $D$ is a second order linear difference operator. The general procedure would be to find a linear difference operator $W$ such that $W F(n)=0$. This way, applying $W$ to the original equation, you get
$$
W D a_n = W F_n \Leftrightarrow W D a_n = 0
$$

Once you solve this homogeneous equation and eliminate the terms corresponding to the original homogeneous equation, you are left with what will be the particular solution (and must compute the coefficients).

This process is normally abbreviated by searching for a particular solution "similar" to $F_n$.

For instance, in (b) you can choose a particular solution of the form $(c_1 n+c_2)2^n$. Substituting in the difference equation, you'll get $c_1=1$ and $c_2=4$, so the particular solution would be $(n+4) 2^n$.

Comment: the particular solution for example for b) is the form $a_n^{(p)}=nc2^n,$ but i not sure

Comment: show me an example of how it can work

Comment: @betmen12 I added an example... In (B) you have a first degree polynomial times the exponential, so you choose something of the same kind. Your proposal is too restrictive and you end up with no solution.

Comment: In (c) choose a particular solution of the form $(c_1n^2+c_2n+c_3)4^n$

Comment: In (c) choose a particular solution of the form $(c_1n^2+c_2n+c_3)4^n$. It is correct, in (a) $(c_1n^2+c_2n+c_3)(-2)^n$, in (d)  (a) $(c_1n^2+c_2n+c_3)(-2)^n$, in (e)  $(c_1n^4+c_2n^3+c_3n^2+c_4n+c_5)2^n$